# Python Iteration Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

```
ai = 1.0

# potentiall edit the 0.7 as I believe this is speciic to the De Sitter Universe
phi0 = (mp * (1/(H_0_true**(2) * 0.7))**(1/alpha))

for i in del_t_range:
    #friedmann equation which is updated every iteration with new values of scale factor
    H = (H_0_true * m.sqrt(((w_m/(ai**3)) + (w_r/(ai**4)) + (w_v) + (w_c/(ai**2)))))

    #H values needed for analysis purposes
    H_vals.append(H)
    time.append(i)

    #finite difference differentiation method for universe expansion
    del_a = ai * H * del_t
    a_val = ai + del_a
    a.append(a_val)
    ai = a_val

    ############################# ISSUE ###########################

    #field potential calculation 
    V = (phi0 / mp)**(-alpha)

    #appended to use for graphing
    V_vals.append(V)

    #print(V)

    #differentiation of the potential wrt the field
    V_dash = alpha * (phi0 / mp)**(-alpha - 1.0)

    #print(V_dash)
    #finite differnce of time derivative of phi
    y_val = yi - (3 * H * yi - V_dash) * del_t

    #print(y_val)
    # needed for graphing
    y_list.append(y_val)

    # used for updating values of phi
    phi_val = phi0 + (yi * del_t)
    phi_list.append(phi_val)

    # Energy Density calculations
    rho_phi = 0.5 * (y_val / mp)**(2) + (V / mp**(4)) * (1 / tp)**(2)

    #calculation required to sort out units
    rho_phi_true = rho_phi / mp**(2)

    #Used for graphing
    rho_phi_vals.append(rho_phi_true)

    # updates values for next iteration of loop
    phi0 = phi_val
    yi = y_val
```

The Following code is looped so I can obtain updated values for variables phi0, rho_phi, yi, V, and V_dash. Each of the updated values are then appended to python lists and plotted. However, I seem to be having an issue with updating my value for phi0 even though I have written that the new value of phi0 is equal to phi_val at the end of the loop. The values for phi0 over each iteration remain the same. For instance,

```
[1.0011701031373587e+30, 1.0011701031373587e+30, 1.0011701031373587e+30, 1.0011701031373587e+30, ...]
```

My apologies if I have been vague or confusing at all, please lemme know if there's any issues. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be wrong. Hence, the problem could came from the loop implementation. If you could show the code of the loop so that we can copy and try, that would be great!

Comment: I've added the full code for the loop there and added that the values of phi0 are remaining the same. I hope this helps and is better! Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @JordanVance, I just put dummy values in the variables that you don't define in your sample, and `phi0` gives me different each loop.